# Excel not showing open excel documents through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get excel 2013 to display a list of all open workbooks. through a user form using the following code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim wkBook As Workbook

For Each wkBook In Workbooks
If Not Windows(wkBook.name).Visible Then
    ListBox1.AddItem wkBook.name
ElseIf Windows(wkBook.name).Visible Then
    ListBox1.AddItem wkBook.name
Else
    ListBox1.AddItem wkBook.name
End If
MsgBox wkBook.name
Next wkBook
End Sub
```

I dont know if the work books are simply not visible or hidden. is there any way to force excel to show all open excel docs?

It works, however it does not display all open workbooks. it will tend to show all workbooks if the previous workbooks are opened before opening the workbook with the code.

this is part of an overall greater import feature. where the user selects from all open workbooks which workbook to import the data from. however the workbook will not display the workbooks if the main workbook is opened first. the workbook in which the data is imported is an exported database from ie to excel.

all workbooks listed in a userform. The workbook for the information is hidden I believe but still editable. how can i unhide this using vba from a different workbook?

I hope i explained this correctly.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
For Each wkBook In Workbooks
wkBook.Activate
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

Also try

```
wkBook.Windows(1).Visible = True
```

or

```
ActiveWindow.Visible = True
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for getting back to me. This did not work. i have since added in a workbooks.count however even though there are two workbooks open it is saying only one is open. but it registers both are both if the excel doc with the code is open lasted. i also tried .RefreshAll before runing the loop. but it did not work. any other suggestions?

Comment: via internet explorers export to excel add in. its where you right click on a database entry and click export to excel. it brings it up as a workbook called book1 or next available name. I'm not 100% sure if it hides that workbook from the system. as it shows open. but the workbook count is only 1 and displays the orginal workbook. Hope this helps. if it doesnt make sense ask and ill try and explain it better

Comment: I made an edit above.  Try  wkBook.Windows(1).Visible = True and ActiveWindow.Visible = True

Comment: thanks man i was playing about with something similar however. its still not working. i think its how my company has the macros set up. i may just ask the development team. doubt theyll tell me though hahah

Comment: as the count is still saying its only one workbook. when there is clearly 2 open....

Comment: Matthew, no its still not displaying as open. i'll send an email off to the developers at my work and see what they will say. then i will get back to you. chances are this will be monday :)

Comment: Devs have looked at it. they have no idea why its not working. but the file its self doesnt have a file type. it may be the way the registry is set up on the pcs thats not liking it when its opened. thanks for your help Matthew